# VBA loop through files in a folder not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

I am having 2 issues with the below code.

1. on the first loop it finds the same file, hence why I have it skip if the file is the same name. After that it will proceed as it should. On the 3rd loop instead of finding the 3rd file (fileName2 = Dir) becomes fileName2 = "".
2. When I want fileName to go to the second file (fileName = Dir) I get a run time 5 error.

*Note: I currently have 6 files in the folder that I am testing but I will want to use for folders that have 10,000 small files

```
    Sub TestMD5()
   Dim myfilepath As String
   Dim myfilepath2 As String
   Dim fileName As Variant
   Dim fileName2 As Variant
   Dim fldr As FileDialog
   Dim sItem As String


   Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
   End With
   NextCode:
   GetFolder = sItem & "\"
   Set fldr = Nothing



   fileName = Dir(GetFolder)
   fileName2 = Dir(GetFolder)

   Do While fileName <> ""
    Do While fileName2 <> ""



   myfilepath = GetFolder & fileName
   myfilepath2 = GetFolder & fileName2

   If myfilepath <> myfilepath2 Then

   If FileToMD5Hex(myfilepath) = FileToMD5Hex2(myfilepath2) And FileToSHA1Hex(myfilepath) = 
   FileToSHA1Hex2(myfilepath2) Then
    'Kill (myfilepath2)
    Debug.Print "match - " & (fileName) & " & " & (fileName2)
   Else
   Debug.Print "no match - " & (fileName) & " & " & (fileName2)
   End If

   End If
        fileName2 = Dir
    Loop
    
   'Set the fileName to the next file
   fileName = Dir
   Loop

   End Sub
```

Comment: It's regarded the same `Dir` and whenever you call it again after it returns nothing, you will get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mashed your code together with the "File system Object" approach, where we can do a `For each` loop on the files.
This at least gets you away from the whole run time 5 error. Maybe it could be of use.

```
Sub TestMD5()
Dim myfilepath As Variant, myfilepath2 As Variant
Dim sItem As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim fldr As Variant
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(sItem & "\")

For Each myfilepath In fldr.Files
    For Each myfilepath2 In fldr.Files
    If Not myfilepath = myfilepath2 Then
        If FileToMD5Hex(myfilepath) = FileToMD5Hex2(myfilepath2) And FileToSHA1Hex(myfilepath) = FileToSHA1Hex2(myfilepath2) Then
            'Kill (myfilepath2)
            Debug.Print "match - " & (myfilepath) & " & " & (myfilepath2)
        Else
            Debug.Print "no match - " & (myfilepath) & " & " & (myfilepath2)
        End If
    End If
    Next myfilepath2
Next myfilepath

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly. It now makes sense why it didn't work the way I was trying to write it.

Answer (score 0):

I think FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) should be used instead of FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)